# How to parse or write jenkinsfile in javascript

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write jenkinsfile from my javascript app. would it possible to parse jenkinsfile so that I can add changes to the existing jenkinsfile. Or is it possible to create a new with any npm package or third party tool?

Comment: Seems pretty unlikely to me. This would be super complicated for little/narrow use. Either your app could allow some very minimal modifications of one or more predefined Jenkinsfiles by filling in placeholders or it could be basically a text editor. Why do you need this? Did you have a look at the graphical editor in BlueOcean? If you still want to proceed the jobdsl in combination with jenkins as backend might be of some use.

Comment: yes, I want little modifications in predefined Jenkinsfile. I am trying to use a single Jenkinsfile for more than one repo by changing the git URL in predefined Jenkinsfile in my javascript app.
For example, I have 2 react applications on Github. Now when I give the repo URL to my javascript app. It is going to create Jenkinsfile for that give react repo by modifying the predefined Jenkinsfile git block.
Please, help me out. If there is any tool or npm package for such a purpose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to reuse the same pipeline for multiple projects, I would recommend you make the repository a parameter of your pipeline.

If you want to start it manually you can set a different default value for each job.

If you want to start it via a webhook (e.g. from github) there is usually some information (including repository url, branch information and so on) included in the payload of the trigger. Personally I use the [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/) with JsonPaths for this, but you might also find the github plugin more useful.

Just keep the Jenkinsfile in one central place.

Alternatively you could use commandline tools like sed to replace a placeholder in a generic pipeline (something like %REPO_URL%) or write your own little replaceStringInFile function in node (but I am sure there must be something like this out there already).
But I wouldn't recommend this approach since it leads to code duplication and different versions all over the place.

Comment: your answer helps me to solve my problem Thank you!